# Prove that $n$ is prime number if $n > 1$ and $n$ divides $(n-1)!+1$

Tags: solution-verification, prime-numbers

Let $n\in \Bbb Z$ such that $n > 1$ and $n$ divides $(n-1)!+1$. Prove that $n$ is prime number.

One of the ways I can think of is to do it by contradiction:

Using the prime number definition that says that a number $n$ is prime if and only if $n>1$ and its only positive divisors are 1 and $n$.

Then I’d have to assume that $n = ab$ such that $1<a,b<n$ and would have to come to that $a = 1$ o $b = 1$.

How should I do the contradiction? Is there any easier way to do that?

Comment: If $n$ isn’t prime, then there’s some $a$ in $[2,n-1]$ that divides $n$ and hence divides $(n-1)!+1$.  But this is impossible, because every such $a$ goes into $(n-1)!+1$ with a remainder of $1$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx This should be an answer.

Comment: FYI [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem), the proof is in the article.